# Kendo ListBox: Return dropped items in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am using two listboxes, connected with each other, that allow drag and drop between the two. While using the reorder code found in another thread fixes the issue with reordering items within the same list, it doesn't address the issue when dragging and dropping an item from one listbox to the other. I understand that is because this isn't a "reorder" action, it is a "drop" action. I've tried many different angles, like using the "add" event, but there is no "offset" property in the (e) object.

How can I accomplish the same thing, that is, keep the dropped item in the order it is visually dropped?

Here is my widget function with the reorder event that properly orders the items as they are displayed in the listBox (why this doesn't happen automatically is beyond me!). Remember, the reorder event only occurs when moving items within the same listBox, not when dragging an item from one listBox to another.

```
$("#myMenus").kendoListBox({
    draggable: true,
    connectWith: "baseMenus",
    dropSources: ["baseMenus"],
    add: function(e) {
        console.log('ADD');
        console.log(e);
    },
    reorder: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var dataSource = e.sender.dataSource;
        var dataItem = e.dataItems[0];
        var index = dataSource.indexOf(dataItem) + e.offset;
        dataSource.remove(dataItem);
        dataSource.insert(index, dataItem);
    },
});
```

Comment: I would study [Telerik's Demo](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/listbox/drag-and-drop) and see what is different with yours. The behavior you're wanting works in their demo.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to accomplish the same task, depending on the html hint that appears while dropping the item in the second listbox. I've modified your code with the solution.

```
$("#myMenus").kendoListBox({
    draggable: true,
    connectWith: "baseMenus",
    dropSources: ["baseMenus"],
    add: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var dataSource = e.sender.dataSource;
        var dataItem = e.dataItems[0];
        var index = $('li.k-drop-hint').index();
        dataSource.insert(index, dataItem);
    },
    reorder: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var dataSource = e.sender.dataSource;
        var dataItem = e.dataItems[0];
        var index = dataSource.indexOf(dataItem) + e.offset;
        dataSource.remove(dataItem);
        dataSource.insert(index, dataItem);
    },
});
```